# SQL server OPENXML doesn't work right?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, openxml

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @str = 
    '<bands >
   <title>my bands</title>

   <band>
      <fullName>beatles</fullName>
      <members>
                 <member age="12">john </member>
                 <member age="13">paul </member>
                 <member age="14">george </member>
                 <member age="15">ringo </member>
           </members>
   </band>


   <band>
      <fullName>doors</fullName>
      <members>
                 <member age="20">jim </member>
                 <member age="50">ray </member>
                 <member age="40">john </member>
                 <member age="30">robby </member>
           </members>
   </band>

</bands>'
```

query :

```
 DECLARE @idoc int
 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @str

SELECT    *
FROM       OPENXML (@idoc, '/bands/band/members',2)
            WITH (member  NVARCHAR(MAX)      )
```

my results are :

[image]

why is that ?

I expected to see the whole members ....
the XPATH `/bands/band/members` is referencing a node which contains SEVERAL childs.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you all of the members

```
DECLARE @idoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @str

SELECT    *
FROM
    OPENXML (@idoc, '/bands/band/members/member', 2 )
    WITH 
    (
        member  NVARCHAR(20) '.',
        age int '@age',
        fullName NVARCHAR(20) '../../fullName'
    )
```

Comment: It was only returning 2 rows because there is only 2 instances of `<members>` in the whole doc. When you selected `<members>` that's where XPath stopped and didn't move to the children. Also, `.` gives you a value of the current element.